# angular: EventEmitter is undefined in embedded component

Tags: javascript, angular, eventemitter, angular-event-emitter

I'm learning angular and I have a problem: I have a component inside the main component and I want to emit an event, but I'm getting an error. Here is my code:

```
import { Component,  OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-control',
  templateUrl: './game-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-control.component.css']
})
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() numberGenerated: EventEmitter<{v: number}> = new EventEmitter<{v: number}>();
  game: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  startGame() {
    this.game = setInterval(this.generateEvent, 1000);
  }

  stopGame() {
    clearInterval(this.game);
  }

  generateEvent(): void {
    const n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    this.numberGenerated.emit({v: 3});
    console.log('event sent');
  }
}
```

this is the html code for this component:

start game  
end game

and here is the app-rootcomponent html:

```
<div>
    <app-game-control (numberGenerated)="numberGeneratedEvent($event)">
    </app-game-control>
    <hr>
    <br>
</div>
```

but when I click the button "start game", I'm getting the error from the attached image:
[image: error]

Note that this is a window and not a component. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
this.game = setInterval(() => this.generateEvent(), 1000);
```

That might seem like an unnecessary extra layer of function calling, but it's important for the way the `this` context is maintained.

Comment: The function pointer you pass as `this.generateEvent` doesn't carry the context of the particular instance of your class `GameControlComponent`. When the function gets called that way, the `this` inside the context of the function isn't properly defined.

Comment: By the way, did my suggestion fix the problem?

Comment: it fixed the problem, but without understanding why. Now I understant why. Thanks

Comment: No worries. Didn't think it was you. :)